# validate a url and then split it into the url and the domain name

Tags: php, validate-request

Let say I have got a url

```
http://ex.com/blah?balchs
```

What I wanna do is to validate if the url is valid. The url

```
ex.com and /blah?balchs
```

How can I do this?

Also if I wanna validate if the domain exists and is up and running how do I do that?
Also if I wanna validate if the url exists and is up and running how do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using built-in php functions for the first part, namely [parse-url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php).

For the latter, it kinda depends on what you mean by "exists" and "running".
The simplest technique is to do a ping and check if that succeeded. But this can be faulty at times. If the target machine is certain to have a port opened you can try [fsockopen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php).